# Empty response from AXIS when contains arrays

Tags: web-services, wsdl, axis

My AXIS 1.4 web service uses complex type with one array and one string elements. When response does not contains arrays, everything is ok, bit when server should return an array, my SOAP response (SoapUI app) is completely empty. Request-response entities are generated with wsdl2java.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the service is processing the request correctly and no exceptions are thrown? Show the relevant part of your wsdl definition that defines the elements and also the structure of the xml you're sending versus what you're receiving/not receiving

Comment: Error found: xml reauest was incorrect - i am missing some required elements. Thank you.